# Raspbian: javaFX Application is not waking up touchscree display after power safe

Tags: javafx, raspbian, touchscreen

I played around with javaFX on a rPi 3 and the official 7" touchscreen. I know that javaFX is not using X11 when showing an application and there are some limitations after all (fullscreen mode, hide cursor, alt-C not workling by default).

But my main problem is the power safe of the touchscreen. After some minutes the display goes black and it is then impossible to reactivate it. Not by touching the screen, nor by clicking with a mouse or typing on a keyboard. It is not limited to my application, every simple hello World with a small UI has the same problem.

Has anybody an idea what to do?

I call my app simply by

```
sudo java -cp "./lib/myJar.jar" my.pack.Test
```

Is there some option or varaible that I maybe forgot to set?

Thank you and BR
Stefan

Comment: Can you try what it is suggested [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=43932#p390181) about disabling the console blanking?

Comment: I allready did it, and this solves the problem. But then the display is active 24/7 till i shutdown the app. Question is how long the display will live then. I'm looking for a way to let my javaFX app awake the display like when I touch the screen